# General Radius of Convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n $

Tags: calculus, power-series

Suppose that you have a sequence {$b_n$}  such that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1- b_n) $ converges. Prove that the radius of convergence of the power series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n $ is equal to $ 1 $

I'm not sure how to approach this. I used the ratio test on $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n $ and ended up with $ \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} $

I'm not sure if this is a productive way to approach. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: By Cauchy-Hadamard, your goal is to show that $$\limsup\sqrt[n]{b_n}=1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-b_n)$$
converges you have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=1.$$
This means that there exists an index $N$ such that  $1/2< b_n<2$ for all $n\geq N$. Therefore
$$a_n=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}b_nx^n+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x^n<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n<\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}b_nx^n+2\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x^n=c_n.$$

$a_n,c_n$ have radii of convergence $1$, by comparison $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$ must have the same radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$\sum (1-b_n) $ converges

$$\implies \lim_{+\infty}b_n=1$$

$$\implies \lim_{+\infty}|b_n|^\frac 1n=1$$

$$R=1$$